# React get ref value with typescript [Property 'clientHeight' does not exist on type 'never'.]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using the useRef hook to get the height and the top offset position of an object in the dom because I need them for some computation. After components mount, I need to store the height and the offset inside a state that I have implemented using the useState hook. However, when I'm trying to obtain the value I need I get an error from the compiler that, even if I understand somehow, I can't solve.

```
ERROR: Property 'clientHeight' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

```
const sectionRef = React.useRef(null);
const [height,setHeight] = useState<number>(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const ref= sectionRef.current;
    if(ref){
      setHeight(ref.clientHeight); //how to get this?
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll',scrollHandler);
    }
 }, []); //call only on mount
```

Comment: Where are you setting your ref?

Comment: In a simple div. Notice that it isn't a runtime error, but it's the compiler that blocks me.

Comment: No, I have already checked this post. Here I need to read the value of my ref. In the post you sent me the ref is forwarded.

Comment: Looks the same case to me. You are just reading different properties of the current ref.

Comment: Sorry, I opened the wrong post I think. I didn't found that solution before. Thanks